# IE10 freezes with jquerymobile application

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, profiling, internet-explorer-10

I have a jQueryMobile website that is freezing up on IE10 (all other browsers appear to be okay).  The behavior is strikingly similar to whats recorded here (https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5695).  I've taken a profile trace of the app at the time it happens, and it looks a bit like this (ordered by Inclusive time).

Here's a link to the full csv export of the profile (http://db.tt/JFTFyeGP)

---

```
handle  135,142 68,758.53   1,018.14    https://webstore.revtrak.com/Portal/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js 2,746       
Function.apply  1,125,502   68,408.73   1,035.73                
dispatch    135,142 68,005.18   550.11  https://webstore.revtrak.com/Portal/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js 3,035       
fn  44,975  63,690.31   65.47   https://webstore.revtrak.com/Portal/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js 3,613       
each    180,179 63,651.23   1,053.31    https://webstore.revtrak.com/Portal/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js 619     
Function.call   1,127,413   63,538.86   119.21              
trigger 135,319 58,534.15   1,247.76    https://webstore.revtrak.com/Portal/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js 2,901       
Anonymous function  89,970  53,944.71   135.82  https://webstore.revtrak.com/Portal/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js 7,400       
Anonymous function  44,972  53,908.56   9.77    https://webstore.revtrak.com/Portal/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js  7,247       
Anonymous function  90,044  53,891.95   693.74  https://webstore.revtrak.com/Portal/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js 3,676       
trigger 44,973  48,471.98   37.13   https://webstore.revtrak.com/Portal/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js 3,268       
blur    44,973  48,395.76   10,987.49               
handlerProxy    134,943 21,274.40   667.36  https://webstore.revtrak.com/Portal/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js  744     
Event   270,452 19,937.73   1,785.16    https://webstore.revtrak.com/Portal/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js 3,332       
proxy   134,955 18,110.55   80.12   https://webstore.revtrak.com/Portal/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js 817     
Anonymous function  134,979 18,067.56   55.70   https://webstore.revtrak.com/Portal/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js  444     
_handleDocumentFocusIn  134,943 17,838.92   206.17  https://webstore.revtrak.com/Portal/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js  7,237       
Date    135,239 17,297.60   17,297.60               
each    90,010  13,440.99   17.59   https://webstore.revtrak.com/Portal/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js 269     
Anonymous function  44,980  10,692.41   55.70   https://webstore.revtrak.com/Portal/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.js 45      
fix 135,142 9,716.28    3,195.12    https://webstore.revtrak.com/Portal/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js 3,141       
off 89,968  9,639.09    46.90   https://webstore.revtrak.com/Portal/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js 3,628       
Anonymous function  44,993  9,427.06    697.65  https://webstore.revtrak.com/Portal/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js 3,655       
remove  44,995  8,729.41    179.79  https://webstore.revtrak.com/Portal/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js 2,828       
acceptData  318,033 8,095.27    3,306.51    https://webstore.revtrak.com/Portal/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js 1,771       
_data   271,656 7,927.21    31.27   https://webstore.revtrak.com/Portal/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js 1,762       
internalData    272,805 7,911.58    377.16  https://webstore.revtrak.com/Portal/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js 1,551       
_removeData 22,490  6,657.96    5.86    https://webstore.revtrak.com/Portal/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js 1,766       
internalRemoveData  22,492  6,652.10    34.20   https://webstore.revtrak.com/Portal/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js 1,645       
cleanData   22,492  6,584.68    14.66   https://webstore.revtrak.com/Portal/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js  378     
nodeType    2,058,434   5,745.35    5,745.35
```

---

And here's the top few when sorted by Exclusive time:

```
Date    135,239 17,297.60   17,297.60               
blur    44,973  48,395.76   10,987.49               
nodeType    2,058,434   5,745.35    5,745.35                
acceptData  318,033 8,095.27    3,306.51    https://webstore.revtrak.com/Portal/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js 1,771       
fix 135,142 9,716.28    3,195.12    https://webstore.revtrak.com/Portal/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js 3,141       
className   271,911 2,112.49    2,112.49                
closestEnabledButton    90,039  4,205.44    1,788.09    https://webstore.revtrak.com/Portal/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js  5,792       
Event   270,452 19,937.73   1,785.16    https://webstore.revtrak.com/Portal/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js 3,332       
type    540,257 1,518.41    1,518.41
```

---

I'm at a complete loss as to where to go next.  From the look of things, something happens which causes 'blur' to go insane.

Here's the user viewpoint.  User logs in, and navigates to the reporting section, where the choose a report to execute.  A modal popup dialog appears, prompting the user for a start date, an end date, and possibly one or two other parameters.  The user then clicks 'save'.  A new window (tab) opens, presenting the report.  The user keeps the report open, then goes back to the report list again.  Selecting a new report, a similar modal parameter dialog appears, but this time, IE10 freezes solid, and you have to reboot, or force quit or similar to get control of the system back.

Any thoughts, suggestions, or other guidance will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm seeing the behavior on Win 8 and server 2008R2.  On server it is via the spoon.net IE10 'installation'

Comment: Wrap the page in an iframe element and for NO REASON (that I know of) it might fix your problem.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato - what a terrifying idea! :D