# IE10 freezes the application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, internet-explorer-10

My application running smoothly in [edge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/microsoft-edge) and [IE11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_11) but as soon as i brows it using IE10 it freezes and can't click any link, all clickable items are disabled. I am using [ASP.NET MVC](https://www.asp.net/mvc) with [Kendo MVVM](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/overview).

There is a little related question [IE10 freezes with jquerymobile application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18519257/3835843) , But not any answer. Have any idea to solve issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my issue for IE10. There is a modal that contains in my layout page. In IE10 this modal can't make `display: none;` so it(modal div) situated hiddenly in front of my main layout. That's why i cant click anywhere and the site seems freezes.

Solution : I have changed code and made my modal `display: none;` for IE10 or later and now it works fine.